# How to reset macOS Catalina Muisc library?

Tags: mac, itunes, music, macos-catalina

I updated on Catalina when it came out and naturally one of the things I opened was the Music.app which imported my iTunes library. For some reason this resulted in only part of my library showing up in iTunes, though I found music in the Music folder corresponding to the tracks missing in iTunes. At some point I decided that I'd use my iPhone to restore the missing playlists and tracks. Instead of the Music app asking which version to use, that just wiped the playlists off of the iPhone.

I made a Time Machine backup and Carbon Copy Cloner Backup of my system before upgrading. And I'd like to use one of these backups to restore my library. However even if I delete the new "Music" folder inside the Music folder at the root of my user directory (which appears to contain a single file which looks like the new Music.app library serialized to disk) it does not appear to reset my library.

I went throughout my user folder, going to application support, caches, deleting anything that looked like it was iTunes or Music app related. Every time I relaunch the app it quickly restores my broken playlists.

I'd like to completely reset the Music.app library and force it to try and re-import the iTunes folder with my tracks and playlists. How can I do this?